# PHP glob() Loop stops after a certain number of loops

Tags: php, xml, foreach, glob

I have a script that reads multiple XML files, takes data from them and lists it as HTML.
Here's the short version of the script (Slightly adjusted because of language and XML contents.):

```
<?php
$files = glob("./PDFs/*xml");
foreach($files as $filename) {
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($filename) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->xml->rechnung_list->rechnung as $data) {
        $belegnr = $data->belegnr;
        $file = glob("*" . "$belegnr.pdf");
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $data->auftrag . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data->belegnr . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data->kundennummer . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data->name . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . date("d. m Y" , strtotime($data->datum)) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<a href='" . $file[0] . "'>DOWNLOAD</a>" . "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

This code works and does exactly what I want, however it stops after a certain number of iterations.
My PHP memory_limit is set to 512M and the whole thing loads in about 30s so I don't feel like there should be a timeout.

Comment: You say "the script stops after X iterations" but do you get an error message...? Is error handling enabled...? Because if you have a memory overflow or a timeout you should have an error message

Comment: With `die()` the script will block are you sure all `simplexml_load_file` will finish?, instead you can use `continue`

Comment: @Juan General error handling is enabled, but the only one in the script is the "or die()" part, which doesn't show up. How would I handle a "too many iterations" error here?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I understand your point but if the script died at that part, I would at least see the error. I don't get any errors so this doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: The " was a copy/paste error. Thanks for pointing it out, however that issue is not present in the actual script. The actual script also works fine and lists about 7900 lines from 15 different .xmls before it stops

Comment: There is no reason for the script to stop without any error message being displayed.

Comment: Where does `$invoiceno` come from? Shouldn't it be `$dataNo`? Also, `echo file[0];` should be `echo $file[0];`. Is this a copy/paste or a rewrite? Please make sure that the code you add doesn't have typos or issues not presented in the real code. Do a copy/paste and only remove irrelevant code. Also, have you checked the web servers error log to make sure there aren't any clues in there?

Comment: @M.Eriksson while it was indeed a rewrite and the error you mentioned is correct, this wasn't the issue. As I mentioned the code works around 7900 times and then stops so the issue definitely isn't a wrong variable because then it wouldn't work at all. I have now copy/pasted the whole part of the code without rewriting anything anyways.

Comment: I admit that I didn't look at your code as carefully as @M.Eriksson did.
Because for me if your code works for 7500 loops there is no reason why it doesn't work afterwards **without displaying an error**.
There is bound to be an error appearing on the screen or in the PHP or Apache logs or whatever.
Your script should stop because everything has been processed or because an error has appeared.

Comment: You say it work for 7500 iterations, does that mean you're outputting 7500 rows in a HTML table? Are you sure it's the PHP script that stops and not the browser that gets bogged down with the amount of data? Have you tried running it in CLI just to check if the output is all there then? Listing 7500 rows in a table in one go seems a bit excessive, tbh and most likely not optimal regarding UX.